# Can we use filesystem without sysfs?

Tags: sysfs

We are trying to work with custom linux which disable sysfs in filesystem and kernel.
I would like to ask how can I use drivers, or what changes are required when using drivers  which are using sysfs.

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

There is no strong link between user and kernel space through sysfs, because sysfs appeared only in the 2.6 kernel.

That will have to do: 
you will not have udev daemon, so the device files you must create statically with a mknod command.

Example for ttyS0 device file:

```
mknod /dev/ttyS0 c 4 64
```